# C# stop a process

Tags: c#, process

I would to be able to stop a typeperf process i started in c# for remote machines. 
What i got so far is:

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();

public void startLogs()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < remote_machines_num; i++)
    {
        string line = " -s " + machines[i] 
            + " -si 5 \"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time\" -o C:\\logs\\" 
            + machines[i] + ".csv";

        proc.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\typeperf.exe";
        proc.Arguments = line;
        Process.Start(proc);
    }
}
```

this really starts all monitors - but i would like to write a function that will stop monitoring and close all windows - how can i do that? thanks!

Comment: Just to avoid bugs in which arguments inadvertantly get copied from one run to the next, I'd instantiate a new `ProcessStartInfo` inside the loop instead of out of it.  This also lets you use the new, more readable object initializer syntax to boot!

Answer (score 2):

Get a reference to the started process and [`Kill()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) it.

```
var theRunningProc = Process.Start(proc);
theRunningProc.Kill();
```

Comment: could i get the processes into an array? if so - how?

Comment: @aaaa - A `List<Process>` would probably be better. Instantiate an empty one and add each process to it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
http://alperguc.blogspot.com/2008/11/c-process-processgetprocessesbyname.html
```

Comment: It would be a _LOT_ better if you summarized what you are linking to.  Probably even ditch the link itself.  Simply linking to the page and not including anything else doesn't help anybody.